# DBMS for complex conditional search with repetition

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql

Goal is to make querying as fast as possible.

Postgres table contains 10.000.000 records, each record has 30 various properties.

```
CREATE TABLE films (
    code        char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
    title       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    did         integer NOT NULL,
    date_prod   date,
    kind        varchar(10),
    len         interval hour to minute
    -- and ~25 more columns
);
```

Users are filtering data in very specific ways, but always based on bunch of conditions.

For example, user A needs to paginate through these 10mm records filtered by column `code`, `title`, `did` and `date_prod` and ordered by column `date_prod` and `title`. And he is performing just few more similar combinations, but he repeats search many times a day. So, main point is: conditions are complex, but variety of combinations is small. Usually just 3-5 per user.

May be this is also important: user wants to see only some columns, not all of them. And this is related to conditions he uses in query.

Records in this table is being updated many times a day and therefore each time user will see updated data, so caching will not work here.

This app is in use by small quantity of users (less than 10.000) and will never exceed this number.

What i need here is to make queries as fast as it's possible. It's okay, if each first time when user creates new search (bunch of query conditions + very specific set of columns) it will be taking seconds to give the results. But if this user saves this set of conditions and columns, i need to make all further repetitions of this search as fast as possible despite the fact that the data is being updated all the time.

I doubt that indexing each column is a good idea. So, how do i do that? PostgreSQL with material views? May be MongoDB or other nosql solution somehow will work better here?

Comment: I have generally very good experiences with both SQL (PostgreSQL, MySQL) and NoSQL (Elasticsearch, InfluxDB) solutions. Both can do the job for you but you must understand that speed always comes with bigger costs. So you will need SSD disk and enough CPUs and memory for both types of solution. Especially NoSQL "magic" requires really a lot of memory. I run both Elasticsearch and PostgreSQL with similar task like yours with 2G+ rows (documents) on instances like 8CPUs/52GB memory but with only like 1000 users - responses are reasonable. Of course every solution requires different "philosophy"

Comment: Use keyset pagination as described in http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset for fast pagination.